# how to read a "char abc[10]" bit by bit and check which bit is set?

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap, char, bit

example:

in abc[2] we find 3rd bit as set then , the actual bit number would be 8*2+3 that is 19th bit is set!!!   like that.

Comment: @Foo Bah hi has 5 questions without accept

Answer (score 1):

you can do a simple bit op check:

```
abc[i] & (1 << n)
```

that will be `0` if bit is not set and `(1 << n)` if it is set

Answer (score 0):

When using GCC you can fasten your bitmap lookup using

- [__builtin_ctzl(word)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fctzl-3060)  to locate the first bit (low order) set in a uint32_t
- (((sizeof(word) * 8) - 1) - [__builtin_clzl(word))](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclzl-3059) to locate the last bit (high order) set in a uint32_t

If you're not willing to use some GCC centric extension and don't wan't to parse your array as uint32_t, you can still use the [ffs()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ffs.html) function to find the first bit (low order) set at each of the array index, see [ffs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ffs.3.html)'s manpage.

Answer (score -1):

This helps?

```
int l = sizeof(abc);
int k = sizeof(*abc);
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    char n = abc[i];
    for (j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        if (n & 0x01)
            printf("Bit number %d is set.\n", (l*k)-i);
        n = n >> 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's `n`?  it appears out of nowhere

Comment: abc is a character array so `sizeof(*abc) = sizeof(char) = 1`.  also the actual bit set is something like `8 * (l-i-1) + (7-j)` depending on how you are measuring the bit in each byte

Comment: I would have done something like `for(msk=0x80; msk!=0; msk>>1) {` instead of the `for(j...` loop.  As it is, I believe you will read the bits in reverse order (I take the OP to be wanting to read the bits as if the array is a 10 byte number, so high-bit to low).